# Saving file to network directory fails

Tags: sftp, manjaro, troubleshooting

I have a text document on a different machine that I open through sftp. However, when I try to save it, I get an error message:

```
Save File Failed!
Error: ENOTSUP: operation not supported on socket, open '/run/user/1000/gvfs/sftp:host=HOSTNAME/PATH/TO/FILE'
```

After I dismiss this error, saving appears to succeed, but the changes are not saved to the remote file. Why is this happening? How can I fix it?

Comment: What editor did you use?

Comment: @Kusalananda Notepadqq